# How i can force the site logo to always redirect to our home site inside office 365

Tags: 2013, javascript, office-365, master-page

I am working on an office 365 project. and we have created 5 site collections. but i want the site logs to always redirect to the following site collection `/sites/home`. now the limitations/issues i am facing are as follow:-

1. inside on-premises site collections, i usually create my own master page (by copy/paste the seatle.master). and then inside the custom master page i do all the modifications i want. by adding the related JavaScript or modify the code inside the master page to redirect to certain urls when clicking on the site logo.
2. but in office 365, it is not advised  to have our own master pages, since we do not have control over the updates and having our own custom master page means that we will loose any updates or new features offered by office 365. and modifying the built-in master page , means we will lose any customization we made to the master page when Office 365 provide new UI feature.

so i do not want to ask a general question on how we need to manage modifying the master pages in office 365... i am just asking how i can force the site logo to always redirect to certain site collection? is there any sort of branding that i can do ? OR can i achieve this using custom css which i can refer to (site settings >> look and feel >> master page) without modifying the master page itself ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert javascript to the sites via Javascript-injection (see https://sharepointconcepts.com/tag/sharepoint-online/). This can be done via PnP-PowerShell CmdLets (Install here https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases)

Your powershell could look like this to add the javascript injection to all you sites:

```
function  SetLinkRecursivly(){
param(
   $web = $(throw "Please provide web")
)
    Write-Host "SetLinkRecursivly "$web.Title" "$web.Url
    Connect-SPOnline $web.Url -Credential $cred
    #Remove-SPOJavaScriptLink -Name HomeLink 
    Add-SPOJavaScriptLink -Name HomeLink -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/home/SiteAssets/myjavascript.js"

    $Context.Load($web.Webs)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    foreach($subweb in $web.Webs)
    {
        SetLinkRecursivly -web $subweb
    }
}

#Credentials to connect to office 365 site collection url 
$url ="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/somecollection"
$username="xxx@contoso.com"
$password="xxx"

Write-Host "Loading libraries"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
Get-Command Add-SPOJavaScriptBlock

Write-Host "Authenticating to SharePoint Online Tenant site $url"
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url) 
#Credentials for the CSOM calls
$pass =  convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $pass) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials 
$Context.RequestTimeOut = 5000 * 60 * 10;
$web = $context.Web
$site = $context.Site 
$Context.Load($web)
$Context.Load($site)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

#Credentials for the Connect-SPOnline command
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $(convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force)

SetLinkRecursivly -web $web

Write-Host "==== DONE ===="
```

The javascript should find the logo image and replace the href

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic").href="https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/home/"
```

Comment: i think i am missing something inside your above script... now how i am going to link the added script with the current site ?? i mean inside `Add-SPOJavaScriptLink -Name HomeLink -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/home/SiteAssets/myjavascript.js"` you are not defining which site collection the JavaScript should be loaded to ? is this correct or i am missing something ??

Comment: now i tried running your script but i got the following errors `Connect-SPOnline : The term 'Connect-SPOnline' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.` & `Add-SPOJavaScriptLink : The term 'Add-SPOJavaScriptLink' is not recognized as
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.`

Comment: After installing the CmdLet you find here https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases (take SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.msi) the Get-Command Add-SPOJavaScriptBlock should work. Otherwise try running a command Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline according to https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/

Comment: Connect-SPOnline $web.Url -Credential $cred connects to the web passed into the function. The first web passed to this function was "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/somecollection". If you don't want to do it recursively you can replace the call to SetLinkRecursivly with the lines Connect-SPOnline $web.Url -Credential $cred   +   Add-SPOJavaScriptLink -Name HomeLink -Url "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/home/SiteAssets/myjavascript.js"

Comment: so you mean the errors i am getting is that i am missing some dll files on my machine ?and running this command `Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline` will install them? then i should be able to use `Connect-SPOnline` and `Add-SPOJavaScriptLink` ??

Comment: thanks for the reply now i download/install the pnp powershell setup file from the following link https://github.com/SharePoint/pnp-powershell/releases . then i restarted my windows 7 machine. i open the SP online management shell, try running the script but i got the same errors `The term 'Connect-SPOnline' is not recognized` & `Add-SPOJavaScriptLink : The term 'Add-SPOJavaScriptLink' is not recognized` .. while i can run the following command `Connect-PnPOnline ` so i am not sure.. should i use `Connect-PnPOnline` instead of `Connet-SPOnline`??

Comment: I don't know if they changed the names from the version I have. Try Connect-PnpOnline and then Add-PnPJavaScriptLink instead of Add-SPOJavaScriptLink

Comment: now `onnect-PnpOnline` & `Add-PnPJavaScriptLink` worked .. and i can see the script is being loaded inside my web pages.. but the logo url did not change... here is the script i am using `var elem = document.getElementById("ctl00_onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic");
  if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
    document.getElementById("ctl00_onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic").href="/sites/home/";
  }`

Comment: also i note that when i intentionaly add an alert as follow `var elem = document.getElementById("ctl00_onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic");
  if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
   alert("Founf");
    document.getElementById("ctl00_onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic").href="/sites/home/";
  }` the alert did not show.. so seems that when the script loads the site logo `ctl00_onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic` will still not rendered yet!!

Comment: I usually use this code to execute something after the SP-site has been loaded: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { ... });

Answer (score 0):

You can add organization logo to the Office 365 Suite Bar as shown below. I have written an article on this [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-organizational-branding-in-office-365-and-sharepoint-sites/)

Select Organization Profile tab from Settings section.

[image]

Here, you can see ‘Manage custom themes for your Organization’. Click on Edit button.

[image]

This will open up the page where we can upload the organizational logo. As per the recommendation, the logo should be of 200*30 pixels for better resolution.

[image]

Once you have uploaded the image, other branding changes can be done on the same page. There are options to specify the clickable URL for the logo so that it redirects to the specified page on click of the organizational logo. In addition to this, we can also specify a background image.

[image]

Within the same page, we can specify the Font and text color as well as the suite bar navigation background color.Once the required changes are done, click on Save. This will show the message that the themes will be applied to the tenant in a short while.

The custom theme will get applied instantly in the Admin Centre. However, it will take some time to update the settings in the entire Office 365 tenant.

[image]

Clicking on the Logo will take us to the custom link.

Comment: but this will not affect the site logo shown on the left side of the screen... is this correct? i already have the organization logo added with the intended url.. but i am talking about the site logo shown on the left side of the screen (just above the Home link) can i customize where it should redirect ? as by defualt it will redirect to the current site home page.. while i want it to always redirect to the `/site/home` .. did u get my question?